# como convertir datos de un fichero str a int

Tags: python, poo

Estoy haciendo una encuesta en python, por lo cual en un fichero almaceno todas las preguntas numéricas.
Al momento de querer usar esos valores me un typeError. Hay algun modo de convertir el str en int?
[image: codigo]
[image: consola]
[image: fichero]

Comment: recuerda que las preguntas debes hacerlas colocando en código en texto y no en imágenes.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función int() puedes convertir string en enteros. Introduce entre parentesis el string que quieres convertir:

```
cuatro = '4'
numero = int(cuatro)
```

Comment: y  si quisiera convertir todo lo de mi fichero habria una forma hermano, es que pro default lo del fichero se guarda en str, pero al momento de querer recuperlar para poder operarlos es cuando ya no me deja :C

Comment: Se me ocurre que guardes todos los elementos en un array e iteres todo el array convirtiendo todos los elementos a enteros